# Максимизировать родительский блок элемента с заданными соотношениями сторон

Tags: html, css

## Описание

Такая вот ситуация…

[image]

…где внутренний серый блок является квадратом (с соотношениями сторон 1/1). Нужно подогнать размер родительского, белого блока за счет увеличения размеров серого блока, максимально как это возможно.

```css
/* Main */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--color-background);
}

body * {
  background-color: inherit;
}


/* Global */

*.layer {
  background-color: var(--color-foreground);
  box-shadow: 0 0 var(--size-shadow) 0px var(--color-shadow);
}

*.depth {
  background-color: var(--color-background);
  box-shadow: 0 0 var(--size-shadow) 0px var(--color-shadow) inset;
}


/* Local */

:root {
  --value-transparence: 50%;
  --color-foreground: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  --color-background: rgb(225, 225, 225);
  --color-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--value-transparence));
}
```

```html
<body style="position: fixed; inset: 0; display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;">
  <menu class="layer" style="width: 40px; display: grid; grid-auto-rows: max-content; place-content: center;">
  </menu>
  <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
    <div class="layer" style="width: fit-content; height: fit-content; display: grid; grid-template-rows: 1fr auto; gap: 1vmin; padding: 1vmin;">
      <canvas class="depth" style="height: 100%; aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;"></canvas>
      <div style="width: 40px; height: 40px; padding: 1vmin;">
        <img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Соотношение сторон с помощью `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;` надо сохранить.

## Вопрос

Я много чего попробовал: `display: grid;`, `display: flex;`, `grid-template: 1fr / 1fr;`… ничего не помогает. Можете подсказать решение данной проблеме?

Answer (score 0):

Не могу давать комментарий пишу через ответ - можно ли у вас сделать одним блоком с внутренними отступами, а треугольнику дать абсолютную позицию? Или же можно попробывать через fit c внутренними отступами:

```
введите сюда кодCSS
    .block{
      width: fit-content;
      height: fit-content;
    }
```

Comment: Соединить блоки нельзя. Это совершенно другие блоки и в них может быть  совсем разный контент. Как вы можете понять по картинке я делаю что-то наподобие экрана. А чем экран больше тем лучше.  Позиционирование на данный момент не важен, но на будущее думаю вариант оставить в центре.

Comment: @Арман а что насчет fit?

Comment: @Арман есть предложение - задать серому класс с минимально возможной шириной/высотой, а потом создавать динамический класс для белого у которого будет изначально класс с минимально возможной шириной/высотой относительно серого - при измененииразмеров серого динамически ввелся подсчет на изменение сторон у белого. Сам JS я плох, так что могу подсказать только с логикой в этом варианте

Comment: Fit с отступами это про серого? Тогда с контентом внутри серого будут проблемы. А JS пока отложим. Я могу это через JS сделать, но так пострадает адаптивный дизайн, плюс то что при увеличении / уменьшении сайта надо будет все расчеты сделать заново. Короче сериал какой-то. Вопрос мой о том можно ли это реализовать чисто через css?